# ordering a list of files in a folder using php

Tags: php, sorting

I am using the code below to display all the files from a directory in a drop down menu. Does anyone know how to make this alphabetical? I presume it has something to do with the sort function, I just can't figure out how!

```
<?php
$dirname = "images/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$dh = opendir($dirname);

while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
if (substr($file, -4) == ".gif") {
print "<option value='$file'>$file</option>\n"; }
}
closedir($dh);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Why are you reading all the filenames using scandir() and then looping through them with the readdir() method? You could just do this:

```
<?php

$dirname = "images/";
$images = scandir($dirname);

// This is how you sort an array, see http://php.net/sort
sort($images);

// There's no need to use a directory handler, just loop through your $images array.
foreach ($images as $file) {
    if (substr($file, -4) == ".gif") {
        print "<option value='$file'>$file</option>\n"; }
    }
}

?>
```

Also you might want to use [natsort()](http://php.net/natsort), which works the same way as [sort()](http://php.net/sort) but sorts in "natural order". (Instead of sorting as `1,10,2,20` it will sort as `1,2,10,20`.)

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate the option tag's text as its `value`.  The `value` attribute declaration can be safely removed.

Answer (score 3):

[scandir](http://php.net/scandir)

```
array scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order [, resource $context ]] )
```

> Returns an array of files and
>   directories from the directory .
>   Parameters
>
> directory The directory that will be
>   scanned.
>
> sorting_order
>   **By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in ascending order.** If
>   the optional sorting_order is used
>   (set to 1), then the sort order is
>   alphabetical in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = glob("*.gif");
if ( is_array ( $matches ) ) {
   sort($matches);
   foreach ( $matches as $filename) {
      echo '<option value="'.$filename.'">.$filename . "</option>";
   }
}
```

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate the option tag's text as its `value`.  The `value` attribute declaration can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

As [William Macdonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2725/william-macdonald) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260387/ordering-a-list-of-files-in-a-folder-using-php#260451) [scandir()](http://de3.php.net/scandir) will in fact sort the returning array according to its `$sorting_order` parameter (or its default: "By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in ascending order."). The problem with your code is, that you generate the array of files in your directory using `$images = scandir($dirname);` but you do not use the returned array in your code further on. Instead you iterate over the directory contents using another method:

```
$dh = opendir($dirname);
while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
    if (substr($file, -4) == ".gif") {
        print "<option value='$file'>$file</option>\n"; 
    }
}
closedir($dh);
```

This is why your result is not sorted.

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate the option tag's text as its `value`.  The `value` attribute declaration can be safely removed.