# display images from a folder in a specific order

Tags: php

In my php project I have a folder named Gallery1 (path is images/gallery1). Which contains images named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 20.jpg, 8.jpg etc. I want to display all the images from that folder in ascending order (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 8. jpg, 20.jpg etc). Does anyone know this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may Help you [Sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260387/ordering-a-list-of-files-in-a-folder-using-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
// Find all files in that folder
$files = glob('images/gallery1/*');

// Do a natural case insensitive sort, usually 1.jpg and 10.jpg would come next to each other with a regular sort
natcasesort($files);


// Display images
foreach($files as $file) {
   echo '<img src="' . $file . '" />';
}

// ???
// Profit :D
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [natsort](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) which sorts by natural order.

Example from PHP.net

```
$array1 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");
natsort($array1);

Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```